# Rails / RSpec Why can't I use the shortened "its(:attribute)" with Rails model associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

In rspec-rails, I have an activerecord model called "Customer". Customer has_many "interactions". I recently spent quite a bit of time debugging something. I got it to work, but the answer I came up with does not really make sense to me.

The following code (utilizing RSpec's 'attribute of a subject') does not work:

```
its(:interactions) { should_receive(:create) }
```

but this works:

```
it "should call the 'create' method on interactions" do
  subject.interactions.should_receive(:create)
end
```

Can anyone explain why this would be? Maybe I am misunderstanding how the shortened method syntax works. I have looked at the docs, but did not come up with any good reason.

Here is the complete code:

```
describe Customer do

    ...other code ...

    describe "#migrate_interactions" do
      context "when a customer successfully migrates interactions from a lead" do

        subject { FactoryGirl.create(:customer) }
        let(:lead) { mock_model(Lead) }

        before :each do

          @lead_interaction = { :user_id            => 1, 
                                :interaction_type   => 'phone', 
                                :notes              => 'test',
                                :created_at         => Time.now
                              }

          lead.should_receive(:interactions).and_return([stub(@lead_interaction)])
        end

        its(:interactions) { should_receive(:create) }
        its(:interactions) { should_receive(:create).with(hash_including(@lead_interaction)) }

        after { subject.migrate_interactions lead }

      end
    end
end
```

And the model method in Customer.rb:

```
def migrate_interactions lead
  raise ArgumentError unless lead.respond_to? :interactions

  lead.interactions.each do |interaction|
    self.interactions.create({ :user_id          => interaction.user_id,
                               :interaction_type => interaction.interaction_type,
                               :notes            => interaction.notes,
                               :created_at       => interaction.created_at })
  end
end
```

Thanks!

----------edit---------

I forgot to include the error that came up when I used the its(:interactions) { ... } syntax.
Here is the error:

```
1) Customer#migrate_interactions when a customer migrates interactions from a lead interactions 
 Failure/Error: its(:interactions) { should_receive(:create) }
   (#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_6::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x0000000af10e78>).create(any args)
       expected: 1 times
       received: 0 times
 # ./spec/models/customer_spec.rb:100:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do can not work because RSpec's one-liner syntax (e.g. `it { should do_something }`) supports `should` but does not support `should_receive`. It's something I never thought to add because it doesn't align with my approach to message expectations, and I don't think it ever came up in a feature request.

There is a new syntax alternative in development that reads `expect(object).to receive(message)`, which *might* open the door to `it { should receive(message) }`, but I'm not sure (I'm not running the project any longer and I haven't looked at that code in detail). If you're interested, take a look at (and join the conversation) https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/153.

HTH,
David